# How to enable asyncio_redis with SSL?

Tags: ssl, redis, python-asyncio, python-3.6

I am using asyncio_redis with my python app version3.6, I have a requirement where I have to upgrade my SSL connections to redis. When I tried to use

```
import asyncio_redis

def create_async_redis():
    url = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6378/0')
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    return asyncio_redis.Connection.create(
        host=parsed.hostname or 'localhost',
        port=parsed.port or 6378,
        db=int(parsed.path.replace('/', '') or 0),
        password=parsed.password
    )
```

I tried to change the connection to use `redis` but the whole application is written asynchronously.

```
def create_async_redis():
    url = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6378/0')
    parsed = urlparse(url)
    pool = redis.ConnectionPool(
        host=parsed.hostname or 'localhost',
        port=parsed.port or 6378,
        db=int(parsed.path.replace('/', '') or 0),
        password=parsed.password,
        ssl=True
    )
    return redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=pool)
```

create_async_redis is invoked using await, when I change the code, it's throwing an exception that the `StrictRedis can't be used with await`

Is there a way to use asyncio_redis to configure SSL?